# What are the grammatically correct alternatives of “kio la fek”?

Tags: phrase-requests

What are the grammatically correct alternatives of the phrase *“kio la fek”*?

*Related question that led to this one:* [Isn't “kio la fek” grammatically wrong?](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/875/isnt-kio-la-fek-grammatically-wrong)

Comment: I want to say something like 'kia feka (afero)' but it sounds strange.

Comment: Isn't "grammar" a perfect tag for this question? The reference to the other question was fine. We don't need to edit this much.

Comment: @CharlotteSL Yes, and yes. Reverted.

Answer (score 14):

If you want something with the same idea of surprise of *Kio la fek* and with similar intensity and vulgarity, go with ***Kio(n) feke ...***

> - Kio feke ...
> - Kio feke estas
> - Kio feke okazas
> - Kio feke estas tio
> - Kion feke vi manĝas

*Kio(n) feke ...* has the same amount of syllables than *Kio la fek*, and has avantages. One, it is more grammaticaly correct, Two, it is easy to modulate. You can create variations depending on the intensity and the source of the surprise.

Answer (score 12):

The expression "WTF" as independent expression is an english or even american idiom, which is unusual in other languages I know. If you want it as a part in a sentence

> What the f**k are you talking about?

you could say

> Pri kio, damne, vi parolas?

Comment: You are correct that it is an idiom, but still languages have means to express something like that (I can immediately think of the Bulgarian equivalent expression). I think I've actually seen *damne* used, and it is a good suggestion. Thanks for the answer! I'll wait to see if people come up with other alternatives. :)

Comment: I like to add -aĉ- in there too: “pri kio vi damne parolaĉas” :)

Answer (score 10):

It seems to me that "fek" was chosen - as an anglicism - because it sounds like the third word in WTF. I've been swearing in Esperanto since before WTF was a thing, and I always swear on the devil (or the beard of Zamenhof.)

- Kio diable estas tio?
- Je la barbo, kion vi faras?

Comment: Haha, I really like the beard "option". :)

Comment: Is 'Kio, diable?' a valid WTF alternative? I like the rhythm.

Comment: Yes. "kio, diable" = WTH.

Comment: Haha, nun mi diros “Kio barbe”. :)